# how to replace strings with "Match case" and "Match whole word" in C++

Tags: c++

I use this function to replace strings in an entire file.

I Need the search and replace to be case sensitive
but the problem is that "Match case" does not work in this function although there is the icase flag include within the code

```
int Replace() {

auto from = R"DELIM(\bis\b)DELIM"; //replace only "is" not "Is" or "iS" or "IS"
auto to   = "was"; //replace with "was"

 //The file is created automatically in the debug folder of the software then you 
 //can put all your "is" "Is" "iS" "IS" options into it In order to check if it works
 for (auto filename : { "A.txt" }) {
 ifstream infile{ filename };  string c { ist {infile}, ist{} };  infile.close();
 ofstream outfile{ filename };

 //std::regex::icase flag does not work    
 regex_replace(ost{outfile},begin(c),end(c),std::regex {from, std::regex::icase}, to); 
}return 0;}
```

How can I make the search and replace process case sensitive?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40577339/replace-substring-case-insensitive-in-c

Comment: If you have an attempt that builds, then please create a [mcve] from that.

Comment: As for your problem, the [regex flags](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/syntax_option_type) have an option for case insensitivity. The "match word" have more to do with your regex.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to present a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your for loop, filenames are not necessary to describe your problem.

For,

Match Case, pass `std::regex::icase` flag

Match Whole word, Use word boundries `\b` around the regex.

Example:

```
int main()
{
    std::string input = "My name is isha. Is it true?";
    std::regex reg{R"DELIM(\bis\b)DELIM", std::regex::icase};
    std::cout << std::regex_replace(input, reg, "was");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
My name was isha. was it true?
```

Comment: Thanks it works. The reason I described in the question the whole function is because I need it for a complete file. and what i did is `regex_replace(ost{ outfile }, begin(content), end(content), std::regex { R"DELIM(\bis\b)DELIM", std::regex::icase }, "was");` and only Match whole word works and not Match case – In your function it works but in my function it is not What can I do for this to work, too?

Comment: @FOREXV it is not possible to help without an MCVE. i.e show code that I can copy paste, compile and run. If you insist on using files for input, put its contents as well.

Comment: Sorry. I updated the question above with all the new problems. You can also see the function itself how I modified it to fit your code. I would like to say thank you very much for your help and I greatly appreciate it

Comment: I've improved the question above Please can you tell me if it's enough for you to help me? And if it is not then please tell me so I can improve it. Many thanks for your help